# Expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1 column 2 path $ on Kotlin+Android

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, rx-java2

I called the PetFinder API to get data. When I wanted to show the data on screen I got this error. I used Call sequence to get data and I used enqueue on the ViewModel.

I tried to use `fromJson()` method but the code gave me error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

My data class was

```
data class Animal(
@SerializedName("name")
val name:String,
@SerializedName("age")
val age: String,
@SerializedName("gender")
val gender:String,
)
```

and I used Animal when I use enqueue method. I created another data class :

```
data class Deneme(
    val animals: List<Animal>,
)
```

and I used **Deneme** class instead of **Animal**

```
    repository.getData().enqueue(object : Callback<Deneme> {
```